# Read lines between two keywords Python

Tags: python, line, fwrite

I am trying to read and write the contents between 2 keywords in a file to cut out the rest of the file that I dont need.

```
** ASSEMBLY
**
*Assembly, name=Assembly
**  
*Instance, name=Part-1-1, part=Part-1
*Node
**Node
1,          12.,           0.
2,          12.,          -6.
3,           9.,         -15.
4,   7.99721575,         -53.
** Section: t3
*Shell Section, elset=Set-3, material=PET
2., 5
** Section: t4
*Shell Section, elset=Set-4, material=PET
2., 5
*End Instance
**  
*End Assembly
** 
** MATERIALS
** 
*Material, name=PET
```

The file I am trying to read is above with the middle section cut out. The code I am using is;

```
inFile = open("Exp_1.inp")
outFile = open("Exp_12.inp", "w")
keepCurrentSet = False
for line in inFile:
    if line.startswith("*Node"):
        keepCurrentSet = False

    if keepCurrentSet:
        outFile.write(line)

    if line.startswith("*End instance"):
        keepCurrentSet = True
inFile.close()
outFile.close()
```

Although I cannot figure out why it is writing a blank file.

**EDIT**

```
inFile = open("Exp_1.inp")
outFile = open("Exp_12.inp", "w")
keepCurrentSet = True
for line in inFile:
    if line.startswith("*Node"):
        keepCurrentSet = True

    if keepCurrentSet:
        outFile.write(line)

    if line.startswith("*End Instance"):
        keepCurrentSet = False
inFile.close()
outFile.close()
```

The above code is the solution to what I need.
Could someone suggest how I could edit this code to not include the final key word '*End Instance'

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you specify what you mean by "middle section"?

Comment: Use `inFile = open("Exp_1.inp",'r')`

Answer (score 3):

A bit of elementary debugging would have shown you two things:

- `keepCurrentSet` is set to `False` initially (It should probably be
  `True`)
- You have a typo: `if line.startswith("*End instance"):`
  should be `if line.startswith("*End Instance"):`

Comment: Could you suggest how I could edit this code to not include the final key word '*End Instance'?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - how else do you define the end of the block, if not with that text?

Comment: I need the text to define the block, but I do not want this text within the file. Could I add some code to then remove the final line containing this text from the new written file?

Answer (score 1):

You may not pick this solution but I would use regex as it should do all work for you. Using regex you could reduce your code down to this:

```py
import re
with open("Exp_1.inp") as f:
    with open("Exp_12.inp", "w") as x:
        x.write(re.sub("\*\*Node[\s\S]*?(?=\*End Instance)", "", f.read()))
```

Here it replaces everything starting with `**Node` until it hits to `End Instance`. You can examine the regex expression [here](https://regex101.com/r/E7e1WS/1) to get better understanding of this solution.

**Output:**

```py
** ASSEMBLY
**
*Assembly, name=Assembly
**  
*Instance, name=Part-1-1, part=Part-1
*Node
*End Instance
**  
*End Assembly
** 
** MATERIALS
** 
*Material, name=PET
```

Answer (score -1):

You are almost correct but you made two mistakes :

First one when you first encounter `*Node` , you should set your `keepCurrentSet` to True so you do get the following lines in your output file :

```py
if line.startswith("*Node"):
        keepCurrentSet = True
```

Second you have a typo : `"*End instance"`should be `"*End Instance"`

Which would give you :

```py
inFile = open("Exp_1.inp")
outFile = open("Exp_12.inp", "w")
keepCurrentSet = False
for line in inFile:
    if line.startswith("*Node"):
        keepCurrentSet = True # CHANGE HERE False => True 

    if keepCurrentSet:
        outFile.write(line)

    if line.startswith("*End Instance"): # CHANGE HERE instance => Instance
        keepCurrentSet = True
inFile.close()
outFile.close()
```

Comment: Could you suggest how I could edit this code to not include the final key word '*End Instance'?